# Como criar multiplas rotas de erro no Angular 2

Tags: angular

Olá, estou trabalhando com o angular 2(v4+), onde minha aplicação tem a seguinte estrutura contendo 2 módulos que são carregados dinamicamente (via `loadChildren`):

**Estrutura do diretório**

```
app
 |-foo
 |  |- foo.module
 |  |- ... (foo components)
 |-bar 
 |  |- bar.module
 |  |- ... (bar components)
```

**AppRouting.ts**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './foo/foo.module#FooModule' },
    { path: 'bar', loadChildren: './bar/bar.module#BarModule' }
];
```

**FooRouting.ts**

```
export const FooRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ManageComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: DetailsComponent },
    { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
    { path: '**', component: FooErrorNotFoundComponent }
];
```

**BarRouting.ts**

```
export const BarRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: WorkspaceComponent },
    { path: 'view', component: ViewComponent },
    { path: 'another', component: AnotherComponent },
];
```

O meu problema é o seguinte:

- Preciso que cada sub-módulo tenha sua própria tela de erro, porque os subcomponentes dela podem mudar como barras de navegação, etc...
- Quando uso a estrutura acima e tento acessar a url `localhost:300/bar/view` o Angular está me direcionando para a pagina de erro de Foo, ou seja, ele não está respeitando inicialmente as rotas do AppRouting e indo direto para Foo.
- Se removo a página de erro de Foo, ai sim o Angular me direciona para o submódulo Bar.

Como posso manter a página de erro do módulo Foo mas forçando o Angular a respeitar a estrutura inicial de roteamento de App?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução quando resolvi ler mais a fundo a própria documentação do Angular 2 ([aqui](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)):

> *[...] The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first. [...]*

Conforme a especificação, para que o que eu preciso funcione, eu tenho que gerar as rotas com a ordenação das mais complexas para as mais simples, então meu AppRouting terá a sua estrutura invertida, assim:

**AppRouting**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'bar', loadChildren: './bar/bar.module#BarModule' },
    { path: '', loadChildren: './foo/foo.module#FooModule' }
];
```

Fazendo isso, mesmo que a rota não exista, a aplicação primeiro tentará encontrar em Bar uma página de erro, portanto posso ter 2 páginas de erro diferentes, e o que diferenciará será as rotas iniciais (ou '' ou 'bar').